# Can you make a Sine wave with a straight edge and compass?

Tags: geometry, geometric-construction

I am trying to make a sine wave with a straight edge and compass, is it even possible?

Comment: Surely the only curve you can make with a compass is an arc of a circle? And I don't see how the straight edge helps...

Comment: Any curve a compass makes has constant curvature. There is no region along a sine curve that has constant curvature.

Comment: Thank you for the simple answer.

Comment: If you are talking about the standard sine function used in higher mathematics, which (in the language of high-school math) corresponds to the sine of an angle in radians, you cannot even construct the ratio between the amplitude of the sine function and its period. But if you assume a given amplitude and given period of a sinusoidal function, there are compass-and-straightedge constructions for certain discrete points on the curve corresponding to angles in constructible polygons. Is that relevant to your question?

Comment: Actually, I wonder: if you add the ability to draw locuses from varying the position of a point along an object, can we draw it?  I know that without them we can get increasingly good approximations by basically building increasingly detailed polygons and projecting, but I wonder if we can do better if we're allowed to animate our way to an answer as we can with many other curves.  It feels like the answer is probably no, but I'm not as good at this as a lot of other areas of math.

Comment: Answer: no.  Being able to move uniformly on the circle and the line at the same time is the necessary ingredient and this cannot be done, as evidenced by the inability to trisect the angle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you liked my comment I will it into an answer.
Any curve a compass makes has a constant curvature. There is no region along the sine curve that has constant curvature.